# Poincare Bendixson theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Poincare-Bendixson states that if the $\omega$-limit set of the trajectory doesn't contain critical point, then the $\omega$-limit set is a periodic orbit, I am just wondering if there is an example showing that $\omega$-limit set contains both critical point and periodic orbit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trivially, a critical point is also a periodic orbit. However, I believe that for any periodic orbits containing more than one point, you reach a contradiction. Recall that a point $x$ is considered an element of a periodic orbit if there exists a positive time $t$ such that $\Phi_t(x) = x$.

Now suppose both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are elements of a periodic orbit and that $x_1$ is a critical point. Obviously if the flow ever reaches $x_1$, it remains there forever, contradicting the fact that $x_2$ is in the $\omega$-limit set. However, if the flow never reaches $x_1$, then we contradict the fact that $x_1$ is in the $\omega$-limit set. Therefore, we reach a contradiction if there is a critical point in the periodic orbit.

Comment: I want to know if there is a trajectory has a limit set containing both critical point and periodic orbit, where critical point doesn't lie on the periodic orbit

Comment: The $\omega$-limit set is connected so the critical point cannot be isolated from the periodic orbit. I believe you can also slightly modify this argument to account for what you are looking for. It is impossible for there to be a periodic point and a critical point in the $\omega$-limit set since the point cannot be periodic if the trajectory also has to hit a critical point